# Move element inside another (parent with same class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move an element inside another within the same parent
That parent has siblings with the same class, so I want to apply this on every sibling, but only for their children

At the moment it's taking all `title` and moving each them inside `image`, so I end up with 3 `title` on each element.

What I want is to move just the `title` of each `item` inside the `image`

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="" class="image">
         <img src="">
    </a>
    <h3 class="title"></h3> <!-- Element to move inside 'image' -->
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="" class="image">
         <img src="">
    </a>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="" class="image">
         <img src="">
    </a>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
```

This is what I've been trying...

```
$( ".item" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).find('.title').prependTo('.image');
});
```

Comment: `prependTo('.image');` is a global lookup.  You will need to contextually find the image in the item, and pass that explicit element to the prepend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//find the title and image relative to the item being iterated over
$( ".item" ).each(function( index ) {
    $('.title', this).prependTo($('.image', this));
});
```